# How can I pass value from DataGridView to another DataGridView on another form?

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

How can I pass values from a DataGridView to another DataGridView on another form? Please I need this answer deadly.

I have a form with a DataGridView, I am using this as invoice so at the event of end_edit for the field of item name I make a search by the first letters of this item name and  put the result in another DataGridView on another form. I need to when I choose the item that I need from the form number 2(search form)  to move to the same cell in the form number 1(invoice form) ?????

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be more specific about your Question

given this scenario

form1 with a datagridview and form2 with a datagridview

you open form2 from form1 you would go to form2 and put sub new in it with reference to the main form like

```
Private f1 As Form1

Public Sub New(ByRef f As Form)
    InitializeComponent()

    Me.f1 = f
End Sub
```

on Form1 show your Form

```
    Dim f2 As New Form2(Me)
    f2.Show()
```

then on form 2 you have access to form1

assuming both tables have the same Datasource` bound

you can go on the `ClickCell` event from your Datagridview on `Form2`

and put in something like this to be at the same position on both DGV's

```
Private Sub xDataGridView_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles xDataGridView.CellClick
    f1.xBindingSource.Position = Me.yBindingSource.Position
End Sub
```

this however will only work if you **don't allow sorting** of the columns otherwise it will be in defferent rows.

if you want to pass a value from dgv on form2 to dgv in form1

then you can do something like this

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    f1.xDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MyCell").Value = Me.xDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells("MyCell").Value
End Sub
```